# PHP Array Select with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have got an inner join working how I want it to when I do an sql query in my database.

```
SELECT debate.date, school1.name, school2.name
FROM debate
INNER JOIN schools as school1
ON debate.homeid=school1.id
INNER JOIN schools as school2
ON debate.awayid=school2.id
```

Returns

```
date        name        name
19-01-2013  st Peters   St Simons
```

When I try doing this with php.  I use the same select statement and add in the below.

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $debates[] = array(
    'date' => $row['date'],
    'awayschool' => $row['name'],
    'homeschool' => $row['name'],
  );
}


<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $debate['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $debate['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $debate['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Which returns

```
date        name        name
19-01-2013  st Peters   st Peters
```

However I want it to return.

```
date        name        name
19-01-2013  st Peters   St Simons
```

In my array I have tried several different things such as replacing

```
'awayschool' => $row['name'],
```

with

```
'awayschool' => $row['school1.name'],
```

but I get an error saying undefined index when I do this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that both school1.name and school2.name are (in php) both named $row['name'], you can fetch one using an AS to rename it

```
SELECT debate.date, school1.name, school2.name AS name2
FROM debate
INNER JOIN schools as school1
ON debate.homeid=school1.id
INNER JOIN schools as school2
ON debate.awayid=school2.id
```

Then change your foreach loop to this

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $debates[] = array(
    'date' => $row['date'],
    'awayschool' => $row['name'],
    'homeschool' => $row['name2'],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query like so

```
SELECT debate.date, school1.name "School1Name", school2.name "School2Name"
FROM debate
INNER JOIN schools as school1
ON debate.homeid=school1.id
INNER JOIN schools as school2
ON debate.awayid=school2.id;
```

Then:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $debates[] = array(
    'date' => $row['date'],
    'awayschool' => $row['School1Name'],
    'homeschool' => $row['School2Name'],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an alias for them.Like `school1.name AS SCHLNAME1, school2.name AS SCHLNAME2`
then these Indexes will be available in your array.Then it will be

```
'awayschool' => $row['SCHLNAME1'],
'awayschool' => $row['SCHLNAME2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following

```
<td><?php echo $debate['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $debate['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $debate['name']; ?></td>
```

to this

```
 <td><?php echo $debate['date']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $debate['awayschool']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $debate['homeschool']; ?></td>
```